# Matching patterns in autocommands

Tags: regular-expression, autocmd

I'm trying to match a particular path pattern for an autocommand. I have this:

```
au BufRead *.md if expand('<amatch>') =~ "/path/to/dir/[0-9]"
```

It successfully matches, eg.

```
c:\soemthing-or-other\path\to\dir\790-798-testing\790-798-testing.md
```

However, I cannot better refine the match: eg,

```
au BufRead *.md if expand('<amatch>') =~ "/path/to/dir/[0-9]\{2\}"
au BufRead *.md if expand('<amatch>') =~ "/path/to/dir/[0-9]*\.md$"
au BufRead *.md if expand('<amatch>') =~ "/path/to/dir/\d*\.md$"
au BufRead *.md if expand('<amatch>') =~ "/path/to/dir/\d"
```

All of the above fail. Why? What am I doing wrong? Is there something about regex patterns in  autocommands I'm missing?

Comment: try using single quotation (or double the backslashes)

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much. Single quoting the pattern makes it all come good. Question is, why some patterns work with double quotes, eg `/testing/[0-9]` and `/testing/[:digit:]`, but most others don't?

Comment: Hi Tom—if you have more questions, you should ask them as questions. The answer section is for answers. I’m going to convert this whole thing to a comment for now; if you want to add an answer or ask a new question, please do.

Comment: @Tom this is explained I believe at `:h expr-quote` and `:h literal-string`